YouTube.Subscriptions.list not returning all subscriptions
I'm subscribed to ~500 YouTube channels and I'm trying to automate unsubscribing from them in bulk.
The first step is listing the channels I'm subscribed to, but I'm only retrieving 9 results using the subscriptions.list method.
Here's the screenshot showing my subscriptions at 488

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried this both in AppsScript (where I'm running the code) and also using the Google API Explorer and the results are the same.
Request:
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed

Response:
{
  "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
  "etag": "[REMOVED]",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 9,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    {
...

AppsScript Function:
function getAllSubscriptions() {
  let subscriptions = [];
  let nextPageToken = '';
  let totalCount = 0;  // Initialize a counter for total subscriptions
  
  // Continue fetching while there's a nextPageToken (for pagination)
  do {
    try {
      // Call the YouTube API to get a list of subscriptions
      const response = YouTube.Subscriptions.list('snippet', {
        mine: true,
        maxResults: 50,
        pageToken: nextPageToken
      });

      // Ensure the response is valid before accessing properties
      if (!response || !response.items) {
        logMessage('No response or empty subscription list. Stopping script.');
        return subscriptions;  // Return the subscriptions fetched so far
      }

      // Add each subscription to the array and increment the counter
      response.items.forEach(item => {
        subscriptions.push({
          title: item.snippet.title,       // Channel title
          subscriptionId: item.id,         // Subscription ID
          channelId: item.snippet.resourceId.channelId // Channel ID (added for exclusion check)
        });
        totalCount++;  // Increment the total count for each subscription
      });

      // Update nextPageToken to get the next page of results (if there is one)
      nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;

    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e);
      return subscriptions;  // Stop execution and return the subscriptions fetched so far
    }
    
  } while (nextPageToken);
  
  // Log the total number of subscriptions retrieved
  logMessage('Total subscriptions retrieved: ' + totalCount);
  
  return subscriptions; // Return the array for further use
}

Result:
4:19:29 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:19:29 PM  Info    Total subscriptions retrieved: 9
4:19:29 PM  Notice  Execution completed


How many subscribers do you have?

On what URL have you taken your screenshot?

Have you read Retrieve all my subscriptions in Google Sheets?

@Tedinoz I have read it, it's not relevant to my issue as it's only returning 9 results and the page limit is 50, so I'd expect at least 50 results in that case. I also believe I've implemented pagination in the loop correctly

@BenjaminLoison the URL is https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/yourdata/youtube?hl=en-GB

@TheMaster to clarify, my question is about channels I'm subscribed to , I don't have any subscribers

@tangybuttz I'm aware of that. I was thinking you got 9 subscribers... maybe that's where the 9 comes from..

Are  you sure you got 0 subscribers?

@TheMaster yes, the 9 it's returning are channels I'm subscribed to, and they're definitely not subscribed to my channel

Try creating a issue in the issue tracker or search for existing issues: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222?q=componentid:186600%2B%20subscriptions%20list%20 Some say setting page limit to less than 9 helps fetch more results through pagination.
